# java script to open hidden divs gets too big

Tags: javascript

i have this code  it works  fine problem is  i need  to use it  for  60 links
that  wil make  around 3600 lines of java script code just to be  able to see hidden content for  60 divs

sorry it was late, so posted wrong code, it was not working,

forgot to mention my  script  is menu with two links  about and help when page loads  the  link is  shown but not the contens, instead  it shows welcome message, when  about  is clicked it shows its content and when help is clicked it replace the  contens  with it

ok fixed my example works fine now.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#welcome-content").show();   
    $("#help-content").hide();
    $("#about-content").hide();


    $("#about-anchor").click(function(){
    $("#welcome-content").hide();   
    $("#help-content").hide();
    $("#about-content").show();
    });

    $("#help-anchor").click(function(){
    $("#welcome-content").hide();  
    $("#help-content").show();
    $("#about-content").hide();
    });
    });
</script>

    <div id="anchor-div">
      <a id="about-anchor" href="javascript:;">
       About
      </a>     
    </br>

    <a id="help-anchor" href="javascript:;">
      Help
    </a>   
    </br>    
    </div>

<div id="content-div">
  <div id="welcome-content">welcome to help system</div>    
  <div id="about-content">About=123</div>
  <div id="help-content">Help=456</div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ryrL4578/)

Comment: Give classes to your divs and use them in your javascript code instead of using IDs

Comment: Can do it in 5 or 6 lines using classes and pull the id from the click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the index of every li to show/hide the corresponding div:

```
$('#anchor-div a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Dont follow the Link
  $('#content-div>div').hide(); // Hide all divs with content

  var index = $(this).index('a'); // Get the position of the a relative to other a
  $('#content-div>div').eq(index + 1).show(); // Show the div on the same position as the li-element
});
```

```js
$('#anchor-div a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Dont follow the Link
  $('#content-div>div').hide(); // Hide all divs with content

  var index = $(this).index('a'); // Get the position of the a relative to other a
  $('#content-div>div').eq(index + 1).show(); // Show the div on the same position as the li-element (skip welcome div)
});
```

```css
#content-div>div {
  display: none;
  /* Hide all divs */
}
#content-div>div:first-child {
  display: block;
  /* Show welcome */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="anchor-div">
  <a href="#"> About</a><br />
  <a href="#"> Help </a>
</div>


<div id="content-div">
  <div>Welcome!</div>
  <div>About</div>
  <div>Help</div>
</div>
```

This way you neither need ids nor classes

// **Edit:** I changed the answer to match the new question. I hide the divs using css (not as mentioned in the commets with js)

Comment: doubtful that 60 links would be all siblings to allow a simple index to work

Comment: The op posted code which looks like a list of links. So I tried this approach

Comment: Thank you Fuzzyma i tried change my java script with Yoyrs but then it just show all contents , and  nothing happens when click links

Comment: yes first thing i did was try your snippet  i can see i works when try it from stack overflow tho its not as i wanted it to show, i had posted wrong  code yesterday that i have fixed  now and  added  jsfiddle example,
and when try use your example from my site strange but i cant get it to do anything.

Comment: Its nearly the same. The difference is, that you have a welcome-div which you have to skip when it comes to "show the right div". Just add +1 to the index of my example and it should work.

Comment: Furthermore add `$('#content-div>div').hide().eq(0).show();` to hide all divs except welcome on page load. I will update my answer

Comment: i man so happy for  your  help, tried your code again it shows all contents on run and help result in both about and help link,
sorry to keep posting but i am really not so good to java script, here is jsfiddle where my java script is replaced with yours and  added the  +1 hope i added it the right place, http://jsfiddle.net/4hj2pwz2/1/

Comment: Last change :D. You have to remove the parent() cause you no longer locking for the position of the li but for the a itself. Furthermore you have to filter the a out of the a, br - mix. Thats why I added an selector. See my answer - its nearly identical to your code now

Comment: ok got it now,  i had forgot to add the css code to my stylesheet,
many thanks! solving  my problem